# Entity Framework connection to SQLite database not working after deployment

Tags: .net, entity-framework, web-config, connection

I changed a dataset based approach to my sqlite database to one using the Entity Framework. I created the entities using Visual studio 2008's wizard and had the connection string stored in the app.config. A client program then communicates through WCF with the database. This works well on the development computer when I host the WCF service in a console application. After hosting the service in IIS7 on the remote computer I get the error: "The underlying provider failed on open". It is generated the first time a read operation is attempted from the database.

The autogenerated connection string is:

```
     <add name="xPMDbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PM_EDM.csdl|
            res://*/PM_EDM.ssdl|
            res://*/PM_EDM.msl;
            provider=System.Data.SQLite;
            provider connection string=&quot;
            data source=G:\PMPersistence\xPMDb.s3db&quot;"          
            providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

(I broke up the string in a few lines to make it more readable).

On the server this is not working, even if I locate the database in the exact same location as on the development computer. Does anything of the rest of the connection string, (of which I do not understand the first thing) need to be edited too? A link to a good resource about how to construct EF connection strings would be very helpful too!

EDIT:
I also added the section below to the web.config file:

```
<system.data>
     <DbProviderFactories>
       <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
       <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" 
            description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"  
            type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/>
     </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

This seems to work (Thomas suggests it should be located in the machine.config file) as before I added this entry I got an error saying that System.Data.SQLite could not be found.

EDIT2:
I installed the System.Data.SQLite dll on the server rather than just xcopying the dll to the BIN directory. Both the machine.config in the Framework/Config and Framework64/Config folders now have the above DbFactory entry. It does not make a diference (unless I have to restart the server??)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The connection string was indeed OK. The problem was that you have to deploy both the system.data.sqlite.dll and the system.data.sqlite.linq.dll to the Bin folder of the web service that hosts the database connection.

Comment: Indeed. Keep in mind that `System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll` does not have any public classes. As a result, just adding it as a reference, may not result in it being deployed (some tools only deploy references that are actually used, not references that only occur in your `*.csproj` file). For instance, in TeamCity, we had to add a manual step to copy the Linq file to the bin directory, and in our installer-builder, we had to do the same. Alternatively, you can add both to the GAC.

Answer (score 4):

Your connection string seems correct to me. Are you sure the SQLite ADO.NET provider is properly installed on the server ? Open your machine.config file, and check if there is an entry for System.Data.SQLite in the DbProviderFactories section

> A link to a good resource about how to construct EF connection strings would be very helpful too!

Basically, you have to specify :
- the model metadata (the parts with "res://...")
- the store provider ("System.Data.SQLite" in your case)
- the store connection string, which varies depending on which provider you use

The easiest way to construct a connection string dynamically is to use the [`EntityConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) class, along with the connection string builder of your store provider.

Comment: What's the exact error message you get ? PS : I updated my answer to address your question about the connection string.

Comment: The errormessage is: "The underlying provider failed on Open".  The stack trace points to the first line in code where the database is actually accessed.

Comment: and what is the InnerException ?

Comment: The inner exception gave the clue, it stated that *a null was returned after calling the 'GetService' method. This pointed me to a post that explained the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Thomas, the conn. string looks OK to me.  But if you are looking for information about building connection strings, check this out:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try double slashes for path ??

```
G:\\PMPersistence\\xPMDb.s3db
```

Also  specifying your assembly name instead of * would help when the application is looking for ssdl,csdl,msl

```
res://YourAssemblyName(without the dll extn)/PM_EDM.ssdl|
```